# Appendix theorem cross refs italicised

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

I am using the theoremref package to cross reference theorem-like environments in my latex document. However, whenever I cross reference any theorems from my Appendix the letters in the name get italicised, e.g., Theorem *A*.1 instead of Theorem A.1. Is there any way to avoid this?

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,theoremref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
See~\thref{thm:a1}.
\appendix
\section{}
\begin{thm}
$\pi$ is transcendental. \thlabel{thm:a1}
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *very* mysterious reasons, `theoremref` adds `$...$` around the reference. I guess the idea is to make the numeric references to appear upright when in an italic context.

Rather than patching `theoremref` I suggest to use `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

See~\cref{thm:a1}.

\appendix
\section{}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:a1}
$\pi$ is transcendental.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for completeness, here's how you can patch `theoremref` in order to fix the wrong math mode.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,theoremref}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\thmref@flush}
  {$\ref{\thmref@head}$}
  {\textup{\ref{\thmref@head}}}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\thmref@one}
  {$\ref{#1}$}
  {\textup{\ref{#1}}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

See~\thref{thm:a1}.

\appendix
\section{}

\begin{thm}
$\pi$ is transcendental. \thlabel{thm:a1}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```